# Python - reading data from file

Tags: python, arrays

I am quite new with Python, and I am having some problems trying to read data from a file. This is how the file looks like:

```
3.25 5.82 3.29 5.81 2.11 3.59
3.23 5.79 3.22 5.76 2.06 3.58 
3.26 5.80 3.25 5.80 2.06 3.61 
3.22 5.81 3.22 5.84 2.07 3.65 
3.31 5.91 3.32 5.90 2.09 3.67 
3.31 5.91 3.32 5.90 2.09 3.67
```

And this is the part of the code I am using to read that:

```
with open("list_spectral_ron.txt") as ron_list:
    for line in ron_list.readlines():
        if (line[0] != '\n') & (line[0] != '#'):
            line_split = line.split()
```

I want to save this data in an array, so I can access one entire row or column (I want to plot this data after).
The problem is that "line.split()" gives me a column vector each time he reads the line and I don't know how to "concatenate" all the lines to form a 2D array.
I always obtain a vector like this:

```
3.25 5.82 3.29 5.81 2.11 3.59 3.23 5.79 3.22 5.76 2.06 3.58 ... and so on
```

instead of a 2D array.

I tried with append and concatenate functions, but I achieve nothing.
How could I save the data as a 2D array??

Comment: Could `list.append()` be what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open("list_spectral_ron.txt", "r")          

array_2d = []                              
for line in file:
  array_2d.append(line.strip().split(' ')) 

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the split function argument:

```
line_split = line.split(' ')
```

Now you should get an array [3.25, 5.82 ... ] for each line

Then just add the line_split array to a total array which you defined outside of the loop

```
total_array.append(line_split)
```